# Use Vue.js components inside Classic ASP application

Tags: vue.js, asp-classic

I’m new to vue.js. I have a requirement to develop a calendar with a scheduling feature for a Classic ASP project. I did some research and found the following project on GitHub which is developed using vue.js.

https://github.com/ClickerMonkey/dayspan-vuetify

I can use this project to implement the feature as a separate application. But I need to plug this inside to classic ASP project since there is no API to develop separately.

I was spending a lot of time to find how to make that possible but couldn't find an easy guide. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The `vue-cli` v3 has a feature to [build the application as a native web component](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component). After building the vue component, you can simply include it in your existing ASP project and use it as a normal DOM element.

Comment: Thank you @Oskar. I'll check document

Answer (score 0):

Using Vue@Next(AKA v3) you can instantiate separate Vue apps on the client.
Simply include the vue3.js client file, extract the desired methods from Vue,
create the app with its configuration and mount it to the desired DOM element.

You'll need to support interfacing, likely when the component is "mounted", between the app and third party object like a calendar scheduler class, cookie class, localStorage whatever you want to support. You can even communicate between app if you set up handles between them. Vue 3 also has providers and injectors which let you affect state and methodology at a parent level and inject it at child levels without the need to pass through each child level.

It's great for learning, rapid development, prototyping, small test components, trial and error type work, but it's a step or few away from typical Vue development paradigm.
FYI, Vue3 also supports dynamic asynchronous components.

```
<script src="/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
const { createApp, defineAsyncComponent } = Vue;
const app1 = createApp({first app configuration object});
const app2 = createApp({second app configuration object});
const vmApp1 = app.mount( app1 selector );
const vmApp2 = app.mount( app2 selector );
```